# WP QUERY to search WP Post and WP User Tables

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

**My Goal:**

I am building a wordpress advance search where the search query is searched to all post (includes title and content) and in the Users Meta Table (nickname, firstname, lastname, displayname)

**My Code**

```
$search = $query->query_vars['s']
$term = explode(' ',$search);


$query_posts = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts}, {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE post_status='publish' AND ((post_title LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (post_content LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (nickname LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (display_name LIKE '%%%s%%')OR (first_name LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (last_name LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (nicename LIKE '%%%s%%'))", $term, $term)
```

But obviously, it's not working because i'm not sure if i'm doing the $query_post correctly. It's not returning search results.

**The error**

It's not really an error but the problem with the code above is its not returning the correct results. It's as if the code didn't look into the User Meta Table. I'm not sure if the SQL query is correct or anything.

Appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from your SQL being wrong.  What would you hope to get as a result?

Comment: More specifically how do you expect the user data to be integrated?